# Should I log2-transform my data before performing clustering with (1-Pearson Correlation) as distance matrix?

Tags: correlation, clustering, data-transformation

I am analyzing my single cell RNA-seq dataset and clustering the cells based on their expression levels of a set of highly variable genes. I calculate pairwise Pearson correlation between all cells and use (1-pearson correlation) as dissimilarity matrix to perform clustering using k-medoids.

Most vignettes and guides I have read instructed log2 transformation of the expression matrix before analysis. When I do so, the distribution of all pairwise Pearson correlation shifted dramatically to the left (all cells become less correlated to one another in their gene expression profiles).

I performed clustering with and without the log2 transformed data and also obtained very different clusters. Specifically, when I calculated Jaccard index between all clusters from original and log transformed data, most index were <0.5.

So, should I log2 transform my data as instructed by most guides on single cell RNA-seq analysis? I am guessing not because Pearson correlation is a measure of linear correlation and log2 transformation is a non-linear transformation and is therefore 'incompatible'.

Comment: No, just use Spearman's correlation which will reward any monotonic association.

Answer (score 0):

Is it surprising you have such high variation? You are analysing a subset of highly variable genes (By your own admission). If you were to increase  this to all genes expressed, youll increase the pearson value. 
As for the compatability of pearson and log2 transformation, log2 is a non linear transformation, but it makes data (especially non linear rna seq data) into a linear “shape” which can be used in a pearson